# San Francisco font: bold + italic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts

In the past, if I wanted to use bold and italic on the same text, I'd select a font by name, like this:

```
font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic" size:size];
```

Now I'm trying to do this with the current iOS system font, San Francisco. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31370170/462162) says it's not safe to refer to this font by name, and indeed, when I try it, some font-related methods do nothing and some crash the app.

Of course there is a `boldSystemFontOfSize` and `italicSystemFontOfSize` method, but no `boldItalicSystemFontOfSize` method.

Does that leave any other way to use bold+italic with the San Francisco font?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023027/how-to-apply-both-bold-and-italic-font-to-an-nsattributedstring

Comment: @rmaddy That worked! I just wanted a `UIFont` object, but that answer included how to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a category based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26023028/462162) suggested by @rmaddy:

```
@interface UIFont (UIFontBoldItalic)
+ (UIFont *)boldItalicSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize;
@end

@implementation UIFont (UIFontBoldItalic)
+ (UIFont *)boldItalicSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
    uint32_t existingTraitsWithNewTrait = [fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] | UIFontDescriptorTraitBold | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic;
    UIFontDescriptor *updatedFontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:existingTraitsWithNewTrait];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:updatedFontDescriptor size:fontSize];
    return font;
}
@end
```

Although this doesn't specify "system font" or "San Francisco" anywhere, I assume the `UIFontTextStyleBody` will return the system font.