# Bold part of an NSAttributedString without knowing length

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield, nsattributedstring

I'm working on app that will take user input from UITextFields for data such as users' first and last names. Later on, I want to display this data in bold.

I've read [NSAttributedString change style to bold without changing pointSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974120/nsattributedstring-change-style-to-bold-without-changing-pointsize) and [Any way to bold part of a NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013705/any-way-to-bold-part-of-a-nsstring), but these seem to indicate that you have to know the range of characters that you want to set to bold.

In my case, I don't actually know the length of the strings until after the user inputs their data...how would I know what the length of the string to set to bold until this happens?

Below are my properties for the UITextFields I'm using, which I'll want to display in bold later.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lastName;
```

And below is how I'm currently creating strings to store the info from the text fields, all of which I want to display in bold:

```
NSString *firstName = [_firstName text];
NSString *lastName  = [_lastName text];
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what you to make bold.

Comment: Should be fixed now; sorry that wasn't very clear

Comment: Do you want to make both strings all bold?

Comment: Yes, my bad; I will edit this to be more explicit

Comment: Do you want to make last name or first name bold or both?

Comment: @narner gotta do that *after* the strings have been inputted, then.

Comment: So what's the problem? Look at the docs for `NSAttributedString`. You don't need to know the string lengths since you want the whole string to be bold. Just use `NSAttributedString initWithString:attributes:`.

Comment: Are you going to display the strings in a text view or in a label along with other fields after the user has entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not know the length of the text entered into your text box at the time you write your code, but you will know at runtime.

Try something like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attribFirstNameString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: [firstName text]];
NSRange firstNameRange = NSMakeRange(0, [[firstName text] length]);
[attribFirstNameString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 20.0f] range: firstNameRange];
[firstName setAttributedText: attribFirstNameString];
```

Comment: That's the hard way. Why not use `initWithString:attributes:`?

Comment: You certainly can.  I wanted to be a bit more verbose to demonstrate what's going on.  We create the attributed string.  We create the range.  We add the bold font to the range.  We apply back to the text field.

Comment: Hi @Axeva, thank you for your comment. I tried to do something similar with the code below, but I keep getting an error that says NSFont is an undeclared identifier: 


    NSMutableAttributedString *firstName = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_firstName.text];
    [firstName addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value: [NSFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica-Bold"]

Comment: That makes sense, and is almost working for me. I'm using NSUserDefaults to save these strings, and when I ran the app and tried to save the data, I got an error saying "Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')". Going to research this now.

Comment: @narner You can't store `NSAttributedString` in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: @narner now you're on to another problem.  I would suggest opening up a new question for how to handle data storage.

Comment: I think you're right @Axeva. I'm still going to mark your answer as correct; I'm guessing I'm just going to have to use it in the same space where I retrieve my user data.